# scope of 'this' inside mootools class

Tags: class, events, scope, mootools, this

I'm trying to define a click handler in a Mootools class. My handler presumes opening a block of links, each of which should be 'equipped' with its own click handler, which should trigger a link specific action. What I mean is let's suppose I have the following HTML code:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <a href="#" id="header">open options</a>
  <div class="optionsBlock" style="display:none">
    <a href="#">1</a>
    <a href="#">2</a>
    <a href="#">3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then I'm trying to define a class like this in Mootools:

```
var myHandler = new Class({
  Implements : [Events],
  initialize : function(element){
    this.element = document.id(element);
    this.elements = this.element.getChildren('a');
    this.elements.addEvents('click', function(ev){
      ev.preventDefault();
      //'this' as a reference to the current element in the array, which is being clicked, correct?
      this.getSibling('div.optionsBlock').setStyle('display', 'block');
      var parentLink = this;
      this.getSibling('div.optionsBlock').getChildren('a').addEvent('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
      //should append the text of currently clicked link into the parent link
        parentLink.appendText(this.get('text'))
      });
    });
  }
});
new myHandler('wrapper');
```

This is just an illustration of how I can imagine the code should be like (and I'm sure this code is not good at all), but I really need some help regarding the following:

1. Since adding new events constatly changes the scope of 'this', how should I keep a reference both to the class instance and the element being clicked?
2. How should I modify the class in order not to have the entire code inside the initialize method? I tried to create separate methods for every event handler, but as a result I got confused with the scope of 'this', with binding and trying to get all of this together really annoys me, but I want to get a grip of this knowledge.
3. How to keep track of the scope of 'this' when adding nested event handlers inside a class? I honestly googled and searched for an answer but for no avail.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

scope, take your pick - asked many many times - search here for `[mootools]scope this`:

[Mootools class variable scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10385560/mootools-class-variable-scope)

[mootools variable scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792508/mootools-variable-scope)

[Mootools - Bind to class instance and access event object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468926/mootools-bind-to-class-instance-and-access-event-object)

to recap:

1. use a saved reference `var self = this;` then reference `self.prop` or use the `fn.bind` pattern
2. add more methods. follow single responsibility principle. eg, in your class, create `attachEvents: function() {}` and have initialize call that.
3. by using the saved reference pattern. you can fix it upriver by delegating events as opposed to creating new event callbacks on parent clicks.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the links. I read the first one before posting my question. The third one is more useful, I must admit. As for saving a reference, as you recomended in your first answer, yes, I did that. It works pretty ok while I don't need to access the event itself to stop its default action. Anyways, I'll try some more options. Thanks

Comment: and actually, I got one thing: if I'm able to `event.preventDefault()` (access the event itself in the `addEvent()` method), then it is obvious, that I can access the target of the event via `event.target`, which also is THIS in a common event declaration (outside of a class). This was the main problem: I didn't know how I should access the element, which was being clicked. Now I know it. Thanks!